# Number only textbox validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var NumberOnly = function () {
$(".number").keypress(function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || (code == 8) || (code == 9)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});

$('.number').on({
    focus: function () {
        if (this.value == '0') this.value = '';
    },
    blur: function () {
        if (this.value == '') this.value = '0';
    }
});
```

}

I'm using the above function to make sure a textbox can only accept numbers. However, if i type 1.5, tha value rejected because of the dot(.). Any one know how i can modify it such that values like 0.5 or 10.5 are also accepted as valid?

Comment: You could use an `regex` pattern instead of this. Also when you are using type `number` why you want to make sure? || Also why down voted guys?

Comment: `.` is `46`, you can add that to the allowed list of codes. But this will allow numbers like `1.2.3`.

Comment: Try using typeOf value to check weather it is number or not

Comment: @programtreasures That won't work, value is always a string.

Comment: It's a really bad idea from the user's perspective to disallow keypresses. Let the user type what they want, then validate the input on submit.

Comment: If you are not worried about older browsers you could use the HTML5 input type='number' element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `46` (ascii code of dot) as a valid code in your `if` condition

```
$(".number").keypress(function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || (code == 8) || (code == 9) || (code==46)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this meets my requirement.

Comment: would multiple `.` dots are valid ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex to match something like this

```js
$(".number").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var valid = (value.match(/^-?\d*(\.\d+)?$/));
    if (valid) {
        $("#error").html("Valid");
    }
    else {
        $("#error").html("Invalid");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="number">
<div id="error"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By allowing key code 46 in allowed keypress codes, your problem should be resolved.

```
         $(".number").keypress(function (e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if ((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || (code == 8) || (code == 9) || (code == 46)) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $('.number').on({
                focus: function () {
                    if (this.value == '0') this.value = '';
                },
                blur: function () {
                    if (this.value == '') this.value = '0';
                }
            });
```

Comment: But now multiple `.` dots can be enter whichis not valid